# Problema con mi Swiper en Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/domain/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/team_match_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/matchs/card_match.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/shared/enums/enums.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class SwiperCardsMatch extends ConsumerWidget{
  const SwiperCardsMatch({
    super.key,
    required this.matchList,
  });

  final List<Match> matchList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Swiper(
      index: 0,
      loop: false,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      scale: 0.95,
      pagination: matchList.length == 1
      ? SwiperCustomPagination(builder: (context, config) => const SizedBox())
      : const SwiperPagination(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 52),
        builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
          activeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 203, 202, 202),
          color: Colors.white, 
          space: 4
        )
      ),
      itemCount: matchList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => CardMatch(
        showState: true, 
        isSwiper: true,
        match: matchList[index], 
        localTeam: ref.watch(teammatchProvider).where((teamMatch) => teamMatch.idMatch == matchList[index].idDoc && teamMatch.type == TypeTeam.local).toList().first, 
        visitingTeam: ref.watch(teammatchProvider).where((teamMatch) => teamMatch.idMatch == matchList[index].idDoc && teamMatch.type == TypeTeam.visiting).toList().first,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Estoy realizando un Swiper para mi aplicación el flutter pero al ir desplazando los distintos elementos a medida que desplazon se van recargando los elementos. El comportamiento que yo desea es una vez llame a SwiperCardsMatch todos los swiper se cargen y no lo haga más